# pixel wise calculation of mean and standard deviation in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image in MATLAB. How can I calculate mean and standard deviation for each pixel?

Comment: have you tried to read some matlab documentation before asking this rather basic question. Or google matlab and mean or std?

Comment: Could you provide some more details?  If you have only a single image, the mean value of each pixel is that pixel's value and the standard deviation of each pixel is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A one-line answer like your one-line question can be :

```
mean(TheImage(:))
```

Comment: I add a second line `sqrt(var(TheImage(:)))` ;-)

Comment: This is a two-line answer.  The code would have been sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. In detail all I want to implement is 1: Convert an image into matrix.
2:Apply median filtering.
3: Decide the number and type of
Membership functions for the input image by
tuning the membership functions. The following
fuzzy rules are used for clustering. like If the mean value is medium and the standard deviation value is low then it is an edge
pixel otherwise not an edge pixel.  Apply Fuzzy classification using the
rules mentioned above on the corresponding pixel
values of the input image which gives a fuzzy set
represented by a membership function. Can you help me please.